# Triggering built-in events programatically OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

Is there a way to trigger openlayers event from console. In this case:
 ol.interaction.Select event which listens 'select' (ol.SelectEvent.select). It triggers when feature is selected or deselected by mouse click.

Comment: You could simulate a browser event which would test the select interaction - OpenLayers has a test script here https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/test/spec/ol/interaction/select.test.js

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time I have found the answer. There is OpenLayers built in function for dispatchingEvents :

```
ol.events.EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent.call(this,event);
```

**this** references the object on which we add event listener

In my case:

```
var fakeOnSelectEvent = new ol.interaction.Select.Event(ol.interaction.Select.EventType.SELECT, [], [], false);  
var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({...});

ol.events.EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent.call(selectInteraction,fakeOnSelectEvent);
```

Comment: It may fire an event but does select a feature?

Comment: @Mike in my case I only wanted my event listener select.on('select',... to be triggered because my logic is implemented that way. To select the feature this way I think you can manualy add features in first empty array parm of fakeOnSelectEvent and then when listening you can add them from that array like select.getFeatures().push(e.selected). That is the way I would do it.